# Virtual Keyboard - Android - Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5, virtual-keyboard

By default when I click on TMemo Virtual Keyboard is shown.
I'd like to have TMemo without auto-shown Virtual Keyboard, I set Hit Test to False, but now my TMemo is not scrollable :(

How can I achieve scrollable TMemo without Virtual Keyboard?

Comment: Make it ReadOnly? Haven't tried (don't have access to my XE5 right now), but it could work...

Comment: Haven't seen ReadOnly property in XE5 yet :)

Comment: So a TMemo in FMX doesn't have ReadOnly property, like it does in VCL? Like I said, I didn't have access to my XE5 at the time, so I couldn't verify it. Thanks for clarifying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "CanFocus" to false.
Set "HitTest" to true - to have possibility to scroll in TMemo.